# check list of accessible repositories to a particular user

Tags: git

I have userName, pwd to access git. I am able to run command

```
ssh peace@example.com info
```

but it doesn't list the repositories which are accessible by user 'peace', 
how can I get that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git has no notion of authentication or authorization.

All you could do is list the git repos if you know where there are.
But if user `peace` has an ssh access to `example.com` server, `peace` can clone any repo that user can access to.

If an `ssh peace@example.com ls /path/to/a/bare/repo.git` works (the folder is readable by user `peace`), that means a git clone will too.